# Thinking of next chords messes me up

Tags: chords, beginner, arpeggios

So as an example of a song I'm trying to learn. Still got the blues for you by Gary Moore. Chords played as arpeggeos with all notes ringing out.
On one hand I'm trying to fix some problems with transitions that aren't perfect..... and at the same time if I think about that change before hand I'm actually just screwing up even more.
How do I give it my attention, without the stress of anticipation ???

Comment: One note at a time. No, I'm not joking. Think carefully about playing each note before you play it. Visualize your fingers moving there. Do not race. Pause. Relax. Think. It's tough to do this, but if you spend 10 minutes doing this, i.e. thinking carefully about each note before you play it, it makes up for an hour of wiggling fingers until you get it right.

Answer (score 1):

When a chord has to be played, strummed or arpeggiated, it's best getting all the appropriate fingers down onto the strings in one go.

Hammering on each chord during practice time is a good ploy. Eventually, all fingers will land together, and feel solid. A few minutes a day for a couple of weeks will often suffice. Try one chord followed by the next, just two at a time to start with.  It'll also mean your changes will be tidier, without the need to put in an open strum as you change - something a lot of self-taught guitarists manage to 'learn'.

A bonus with such a song is that those changes occur in many other songs, in different keys, so actually, you're sort of learning other new stuff unknowingly!

Were 'on one hand' and 'before hand' chosen specially?